# What is this costume inspired by?

Tags: costume

Does this costume have an origin in some sort of film, comic or game?

[image]

Comment: Where is this image from?

Comment: And is it cropped?

Comment: @Valorum ahh, never mind then! - It does look cropped and google has no idea where it came from...

Comment: It looks like a shot from a promotional booth at a convention.

Comment: I came across an image on Tumblr by chance that reminded me of your question. Might this be from Neon Genesis Evangelion? I cant find a character that looks exactly the same, but the things poking out of the armor look similar... : https://www.google.com/search?q=Neon+Genesis+Evangelion&rlz=1C1CHZL_enUS682US682&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi82t2ezMLZAhVS8GMKHeSMB3cQ_AUICigB&biw=1367&bih=821#imgdii=xBwfgtA7O-YxQM:&imgrc=fuHxkDFQwFp_eM:

Comment: If you post the entire picture, we can do a reverse image search on it. The text that's cut off on the side might also give a clue.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This picture along with the question was sent to me by a friend, who says it was taken in a dance club (in Europe). I'm guessing it is a made up design then...

Comment: This is off topic, unless you can show that the "film, comic, or game" that inspired the costume contain elements of science fiction or fantasy.

Comment: @user14111 Granted, I was hoping that someone on here could show that...

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of Diva Plavalaguna from Fifth Element. Especially the "hair" and the hip ornaments.

[image]

Comment: Granted there are similarities, but there are also a fair number of differences.  I think it's safe to say this isn't related.